# Tracking Web App Page Close, AJAX request cancelled

Tags: mootools, analytics, onbeforeunload, mixpanel

I have some web app. It is desktop based. I have an issue where the action is getting canceled before I save my data. I am using an unload event in javascript to send some data to mixpanel (just some ajax call). The problem is that I believe that this request gets "cancelled" on occasion.

Is there a way to prevent the page from changing until I get to a callback? I feel like the answer is a no unless I am able to make the call synchronous. I don't think I have that ability with mixpanel.

I am currently using the unload event in mootools. I should probably use beforeunload? Is there a way to tell unload that I am done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no.  Synchronous ajax would appear to be the only reliable option here.

If you're controlling the client-side code, it's easy to make it synchronous.  Simply add `async: false` ton your `Request` options.  The server won't care.

One potential gotcha for those of us accustomed to writing asynchronous ajax:  Nothing after the `Request.send()` call will get executed until after the `onComplete` handler is done.  This means that details such as displaying "Please wait..." have to appear first in the code.  With asynchronous requests, the order obviously doesn't matter, and it's common to send the request first.

As for `beforeunload`, it's probably not useful here.  The value of `beforeunload` is to allow the user to cancel the impending page load.  If you don't need this functionality, go with `unload`.

Answer (score 1):

There's a newer approach using `navigator.sendBeacon`. The following sets up a mixpanel event for navigating away from the page.

```js
var props = {};
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function() {
    if (document.visibilityState === 'hidden') {
        mixpanel.track('Page closed', props, {transport: 'sendBeacon'});
    }
});
```

`{transport: 'sendBeacon'}` is something available in mixpanel js as of Jan 2020 as [discussed in this github issue](https://github.com/mixpanel/mixpanel-js/issues/184#issuecomment-571782319). There's (proposed, prior to implementation) snippet in that discussion, but I think it should say "beforeunload" not "unload". But then I found...

The [developer.mozilla.org documentation on navigator.sendbeacon includes a very relevant section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon#sending_analytics_at_the_end_of_a_session) advising using "visibilitychange" instead of "unload" or "beforeunload" for this tracking purpose. This event fires even if a user swaps to a different tab (Not exactly "closing" the page. Maybe not what's expected), but it also fires if a mobile browser user opens a different app (Probably *is* what's expected, since that's pretty much the main way you "close" the page on a mobile).